# storing nsdictionay in nsarray using separator

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to display an image and some text under that image,, i was thinking of using NSDictionary :

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Tree:shajrah", @"1", 
                      @"Milk:haleeb", @"2", 
                      nil];
NSString *sep = @":";
```

I want to know after this step how can I store it in NSArray using separator?

Thank you,
Dalal

Comment: What do you want do do exactly with your separator ?

Comment: Actually I have to use five objects for each key.. my page will display a picture , name of that image in english and in other language + sound ... so that's why i'm using a separator.... do you suggest any other way in storing these objects??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very good design. Instead, you should create a new class that contains the UIImage and the text as properties (and anything else you need), and replace your NSDictionary with NSArray of your class.